# Lookup/evaluate 2 range in worksheet A before paste value in worksheet B

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting:

> Mismatch error, runtime 13

```
Sub Lookup()

For Each Cell In Workbooks("ID.xlsx").Worksheets("ID").Range("B:B")

If Range("B:B").Cells.Value = "RM" Then

End If

Next

For Each Cell In Workbooks("ID.xlsx").Worksheets("ID")

If Range("C:C").Cells.Value = "Sales $" Then

Workbooks("ABC_Actuals and Targets.xlsm").Worksheets("ID").Cells(9, 7).Value = Workbooks("ID.xlsx").Worksheets("ID").Range("BM:BM").Value

End If

Next

End Sub
```

I intend to make Excel loop through cells in ranges in B:B of Ws Source, if True then Loop through cells in ranges C:C of Ws Source, if True then
Copy Value of that row, in column BL of Ws Source Paste Value into designated Ws Destination Cell (9,7).

There are many columns in Ws Source. Example :
With Ws Source:
Look for RM in column B, then look for Sales $ in column C, if these 2 is true, Copy value in columnn BL of that row and PasteValue to Cells(9, 7) in Ws Destination.

In Ws Source, there are 43 "RM" (s) column B and 58 "Sales $" in column C.
A row is unique when "RM" in column B and "Sales $" in Ws Source occurs.

Which I intend to set value of Destination Wbk.Cell (9,7) to column BL of that unique Ws Source mentioned above.

Comment: Should `If Range("B:B").Cells.Value = "RM"` be `if cell.value="RM"`?

Comment: I don't think you can paste `Range("BM:BM").Value` to `Cells(9, 7)`. Try Copy and then Paste in the next line. And why are you looping through all cells in the sheet, examine each one if it's "RM" and then do nothing, whatever the result of that examination?

Comment: @Variatus edited question for better clarity

Comment: @Nathan_Sav edited for better clarity

Comment: must "Sales $" in column C be found in the same row where "RM" has been found in column B?

Comment: @HTH 
Yes they must

Comment: @Eric1234, ok. Then you mught want to see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is a fair interpretation of what you have explained above. Please try it. Also take note of the comments. They will help you understand how the logic is built in VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Lookup_DoSomething()            ' "Lookup" is the name of an Excel function

    ' always declare all your variables, especially the objects!
    '   Use Option Explicit to help you

    Dim WsS As Worksheet            ' Source sheet
    Dim WsD As Worksheet            ' Destination sheet
    Dim Cell As Range

    ' Note: both workbooks must be open or an error will occur
    Set WsS = Workbooks("ID.xlsx").Worksheets("ID")
    Set WsD = Workbooks("ABC_Actuals and Targets.xlsm").Worksheets("ID")

    ' use proper indenting to help you read your code
    '   and better understand its logic
    For Each Cell In Ws.Range("B:B")
        ' 'Cell.Offset(0, 1)' is in column C
        If Cell.Value = "RM" And Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Sales $" Then
            WsD.Cells(9, 7).Value = WsS.Cells(Cell.Row, "BL").Value
            ' I think you need to end the loop when the value was found
            ' if you don't do that the loop will continue writing to
            ' the same cell and you get to see only the last one found.
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Cell                       ' always specify which "Next"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a beginner to codes, please forgive me:

Which part of this would then cycle through C:C to look for criterion "Sales $"?
I see that after RM, it takes immediately to column C via 0,1 but there are 20 RM(s) and there is need to cycle to C:C and find "Sales $" before arriving at the right cell to set value?

Comment: Imagine you find "RM" in B8. Then you cycle through C:C and find "Sales $" in row 24. I couldn't find the sense. Therefore I presumed that *Sales $* would be in the same row 8 but in column C. No need for looping because the row is already found. If this presumption is wrong you must better explain your data setup. If you remove the `Exit For` the loop can find all the instances of "RM" but you have provided only one cell to write to, Cells(9, 7). Where should the other values go?

Comment: There are 43 RM (s) in column B and 58 "Sales $" in column C

The right row is only when "Sales $" is in C:C and "RM" in B:B coincide.

The value to be applied to WsD Cells(9,7) is in WsS column BL of that row.

Comment: OK. Understood. (1) Which value is to be transferred? B = "RM" and C = "Sales $". So, which column do you want to transfer the value from? (2) You have 43 values to transfer but only one cell to paste them to. If 43 values are pasted to the same cell, each new pasting will erase the previous. So, you only get to see the last.

Comment: (1) There is only 1 row in the file where B = "RM" and C = "Sales". Column BL is the column of that 1 row where is value is situated in WsS.
What the code is doing now is identifying RM but it is an array of 43 rows.
Only after applying 2nd criterion if C = "Sales" would it be 1 row, n column BL of that row houses the value to be transfer from.
(2) If the row above is 8, then BL column should be 64.

Comment: I have amended the case to better reflect the data setup.

Comment: BTW, a SUMIFS() function in WsD.Cells(9, 7) would extract the value faster and easier than the Sub we're working on. We still haven't come to what to do if the value isn't found but unless the sub is to be bound into a larger automation project really requiring VBA capabilities you should be better off with a worksheet function. And if you do need VBA for other reasons you should use that same function but called from VBA in place of the loop we have been trying to construct.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wsS As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    'Set the workbooks
    Set wsS = Workbooks("ID.xlsx").Worksheets("ID")
    Set wsD = Workbooks("ABC_Actuals and Targets.xlsm").Worksheets("ID")

    With wsS
        'Find the last row of column B to avoid looping all column
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        'Import the values in an array to be more fast
        arr = .Range("A1:C" & LastRow)
        'Loop array
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            'If both conditions met
            If arr(i, 1) = "RM" And arr(i, 2) = "Sales $" Then
                'Import in the destination workbook the value of column C
                With wsD
                    .Cells(9, 7).Value = arr(i, 3)
                End With

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: While there are no errors/debugging, no value is updated in Cell 9,7.

Comment: Go through the code and check the values, the conditions & the ranges. If you have further questions please let m know.

Answer (score 0):

that would be an `AutoFilter` job, but here's a possible `Find()` soultion:

```
Sub LookupTest()
    Dim f As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    With Workbooks("ID.xlsx").Worksheets("ID")
        With .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            Set f = .Find(what:="RM", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = f.Address
                Do
                    If f.Offset(, 1).Value = "Sales $" Then
                        Workbooks("ABC_Actuals and Targets.xlsm").Worksheets("ID").Cells(9, 7).Value = .Cells(f.Row, "BL").Value
                        MsgBox "Done"
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                    Set f = .FindNext(f)
                Loop While f.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
        End With
    End With
    MsgBox "No such match!"
End Sub
```

Edit to add an `AutofIlter` based solution:

```
    With Workbooks("ID.xlsx").Worksheets("ID")
        With .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="RM"
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="Sales $"
            Workbooks("ABC_Actuals and Targets.xlsm").Worksheets("ID").Cells(9, 7).Value = _
                .Parent.Cells(.Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Rows(1).Row, "BL").Value
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
```

and where it's assumed a match is always found

Comment: I have tried, so far its "No such match!". I'll relook again if there are any references that are errorneous on my end.
Super thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Have you also tried the second code?